# Проблемы с загрузкой ВКонтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

```
    <?php

class Model_Vk {

    private $access_token;
    private $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/";

    public function __construct($access_token) {

        $this->access_token = $access_token;
    }

    public function method($method, $params = null) {

        $p = "";
        if( $params && is_array($params) ) {
            foreach($params as $key => $param) {
                $p .= ($p == "" ? "" : "&") . $key . "=" . urlencode($param);
            }
        }
        $response = file_get_contents($this->url . $method . "?" . ($p ? $p . "&" : "") . "access_token=" . $this->access_token);

        if( $response ) {
            return json_decode($response);
        }
        return false;
    } }

$access_token = "***"; $id = ***;

$vk = new Model_Vk($access_token);

$params = array(
    "gid" => $id ); $data_json = $vk->method("photos.getWallUploadServer", $params); $upload_url = ''; foreach($data_json as $key => $value) {
    $upload_url = $value->upload_url; }

$files = array('1.jpg'); $temp = array_chunk($files, 4); $attachments = array();

foreach ($temp[0] as $key => $data) {
    echo $path = realpath($data);

    if($path){
        $files['file' . ($key+1)] = '@' . realpath($data);
    } }

$ch = curl_init($upload_url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data")); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files);

$upload_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

$response = $vk->method('photos.saveWallPhoto', $upload_data);

if(count($response) > 0){

    foreach($response as $key => $value){

        $attachments[] = $value->id;
    } }

print_r($attachments);

?>
```

Хочу загрузить на группу вк фотографию, выдает такой ответ

> [error_code] => 121 [error_msg] =>
> Invalid hash

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку: судя по `photos.saveWallPhoto` вы грузите фото на стену. А для этого нужно использовать не `photos.getWallUploadServer`, а `wall.getPhotoUploadServer`.